# What does "recode x .=0" do in Stata?

Tags: stata

Can anyone tell me, what's this line of Stata code doing?

```
recode cost_per_item .=0
```

I know that `cost_per_item` is a previously created variable, and `recode` is transforming the value somehow. But I don't know what `.=0` is in this context, and the docs aren't helping.

Comment: Please stop prefixing your questions with information already available in the tags. The tag system works extremely efficiently here; it doesn't need help.

Comment: Personally I hate it when people don't prefix questions with tags - I regularly click on "Related" questions in the sidebar only to find that they're for a completely different language.

Comment: Have amended title to make clear it's for Stata.

Comment: The **tag** makes it clear it's for Stata. The extra noise and clutter in the title are unnecessary (as I mentioned before). If you're not clear how tags work, you should learn. They're quite efficient at getting questions in front of people who monitor them. The fact you haven't learned how to use them properly doesn't mean that everyone else has the same lack of understanding. Let the **tag** do it's job, and avoid the redundant nonsense in the title itself. It leaves more room for your question, and makes the question easier to read.

Comment: @KenWhite wow, you seem to feel strongly about this. I explained the UX problem I have above. How do you propose to solve it? (If you're not sure about what UX is, or why it matters, I can point you at some resources.)

Comment: I'm quite aware of what UX is; thanks for the condescension. I propose you solve it by learning how to use tags and filters, rather than add garbage to the title of each and every question you post; if you're not sure how to learn to use them properly, I can point you to some resources that seem to have worked for about 99% of the other SO users.

Comment: Note how all the questions in the "Related" list for this post contain the word "Stata"? That's because all those other users wanted the language name in the title too, for exactly the same reason as me. Can you point me to the source for the "about 99%" you quote? And yes, please do show me how to get the "Related" list to only show Stata resources using tags.

Comment: Also, why the downvote? This question is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: You're *assuming* I downvoted (which I did not). If you tag your question *Stata*, the Related list handles that automatically. You can also add the Stata tag as one of your favorite tags, and posts on the main page that contain that tag will be highlighted to bring them to your attention. The 99% are the vast majority of posts here that do not put redundant tag information in the titles and don't require it in order to find posts in languages they're interested in following. Review the first 100 pages of posts, and you'll see vast quantities that don't contain tags. Noobs usually use them.

Comment: @KenWhite the downvote question was general.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks, although that doesn't solve the UX problem of landing on a question page, seeing promising-looking answers in the "Related" list, clicking on them and finding they're for a totally different language. This happens to me all the time. Using the tag in the title was an attempt to solve that UX problem, not due to not understanding how tags work.

Comment: Look, this is my problem. I'm writing a new question about pandas, so I've tagged it `pandas`. Yet all the suggested answers are not for pandas: http://imgur.com/wXEruwU I can only tell this because the authors have included the language name in the title. If they hadn't, my UX would be to click on them, then click "back", repeatedly. That's why I find it helpful when people include the language/tag name in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the output of `help missing` for important background on "missing values" in Stata. Your recode statement is replacing a missing value represented as `.` with a numeric value of zero, leaving other values of your variable `cost_per_item` unchanged. The name of the variable suggests that the missing value may have been generated by a calculation that included division by zero, for example `cost_per_item = total_cost / total_items` when no such items were produced.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.